# Restore an old version of a quality profile in Sonar

Tags: sonarqube

During an upgrade, Sonar decided to deactivate all the rules in my quality profile A. I now have version 5 of it (with all my rules) and version 6 (with no rules). I can see the difference in the changelog, but I do not know how to restore v5 of the profile. Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. The only way is to start from your database backup.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's an answer. Not the one I was hoping for though :) I wanted to report a feature request, do you know if I should be able to do it [on this link](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Aissues-panel)?